# Query on New Zealand immigration

Tags: working-visas, immigration, new-zealand

I've worked with major internet companies for the last 7 years as a Systems engineer/System Administrator in Bangalore, IN and I'd like to immigrate to New Zealand to work and live there. Although I sat through the classes of my Bachelor's engineering program I haven't been able to finish it due to personal/financial issues. I have a total of 9 years industrial experience, would that help make up for the missing degree ?

Comment: I don't understand the close vote as "off-topic." The OP is asking about educational and work experience requirements for emigrating to another country.

Comment: Oops. Looks like this is not the place to ask my question or probably folks are unaware what to suggest because of my degree situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question is whether you would be considered under "skilled employment".  Under the list of [skilled occupations](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/opsmanual/35165.htm), we do find in Part A:

> 263111 Computer Network and Systems Engineer

The next is whether your experience can substitute for a formal qualification. Generally this would be five years experience, but we have to check ANZSCO to be sure.  [Here is](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/Product+Lookup/1220.0~2013,+Version+1.2~Chapter~UNIT+GROUP+2631+Computer+Network+Professionals) the appropriate page:

> Most occupations in this unit group have a level of skill commensurate with a bachelor degree or higher qualification. At least five years of relevant experience and/or relevant vendor certification may substitute for the formal qualification. In some instances relevant experience and/or on-the-job training may be required in addition to the formal qualification (ANZSCO Skill Level 1).

So therefore, you may be able to qualify. You still have to earn enough points - the big factor there is having a job offer, but other factors (such as your age, if you have relatives in NZ, if you are applying alone or with spouse) will also impact your score.

Look through the [Quick Check](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/skilledmigrant/caniapply/) to make sure you would be eligible for the skilled migrant category and then get an estimate of your [total points](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/pointsindicator/), presuming that you have a job offer.